# UITextField in a storyboard static UITableViewCell is not accepting input

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, storyboard

I have created a static tableview cell containing a UITextField using storyboards in Xcode 4.5.2 (this also happens in 4.6 DP1).  Tapping on the UITextField brings up the keyboard, but the text field does not accept input from the keyboard.  If I add text to the field programatically, the text will appear, but I am still not able to add text via the keyboard (or via the main keyboard when using the simulator).  The only key that does work on the keyboard is the "Delete" key.  Has anyone experienced this and know what the cause may be?

Comment: Have you implemented any of the UITextFieldDelegate methods that could prevent changes like shouldChangeCharactersInRange or didChande....?  If so, post that code....

Comment: Thank you.  I found that the issue was SVProgressHUD (see comments under next answer).

Answer (score 0):

Does the textField has IBOutlet property, and also you connect IBOutlet in storyboard?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Yes, I had everything wired up properly, but I also found that the issue was SVProgressHUD.  I removed the library and everything started working properly.  I will investigate that more as I was using the latest version of that code.